# How post Image and Link URL in Google Plus from Android Application?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

i have try to post Image from server and link URL both in google plus from android application.. but i can't post both in google plus..

i have try this code to post..

```
Intent shareIntent = new 

PlusShare.Builder(GooglePlusActivity.this)
                  .setType("text/plain")
                  .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform....")

                  .setContentDeepLinkId("/cheesecake/lemon", 
                          "Lemon Cheesecake recipe", 
                          "A tasty recipe for making lemon cheesecake.",
                          Uri.parse("http://www.onedigital.mx/ww3/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/android-420x315.jpg"))
                  .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
                  .getIntent();`
```

In tthis code i have only post a image but not post URL.. URl is display but it not clickable.

some one give me solution for my problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `google-play-services_lib` library project. Just import it in workspace in add in your project.

You can find it at **.../android-sdk-linux_x86/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject**

And use this code for sharing on google-plus via google-plus application.

```
final int errorCode = GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp(mActivity);
if (errorCode == GooglePlusUtil.SUCCESS) {
// Invoke the ACTION_SEND intent to share to Google+ with attribution.
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(mActivity)
                                .setText("")
                                .setType("text/plain")
                                .getIntent()
                                .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
    startActivity(shareIntent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Google plus not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i already use this lib..i successfully share URL on Google plus and also share image individually but URL takes picture directly from its content but i want to share text with content URL and on URL link i need Picture of my choice(ex. If i share play store link then on Google+ it will take default image of play store i need my image display on this link)....so please help me....

Comment: **If i share play store link then on Google+ it will take default image of play store i need my image display on this link**, is it possible ?? I don't think so it is possible..

Comment: you r right dude.. **but play store link with my own image is  share in Google plus is my basic requirement.** so please some one help me..

Comment: I am try this code also.. but it's not work.


 Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)

          .setType("text/plain")
          .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
          .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
          .getIntent();
      startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);

this only share a link ...

Comment: Hi @CapDroid, in this code intent is used; meaning if Google+ app is not installed on Device then this will not work. But can we share image without this dependency? I want to share image with text on G+ but there should not be dependency like this. I have also posted question on SO here....if you can help me on this then it would be very great for me..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955084/share-photo-on-google-plus-using-android-sdk-not-by-share-intent

Comment: If google provided any SDK or API for this then it is possible, I never looked for this, so no more idea...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to share an image and give the URL in the accompanying text. See the PlusShare documentation:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/media

It says: *When you share media to Google+, you cannot also use the setContentUrl method. If you want to include a URL in the post with the media, you should append the URL to the prefilled text in the setText() method.*

Answer (score 0):

Add your media url with text message in **.setText** field

> ```
> Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
>                               .setType("text/plain")
>                               .setText("Sharing text with image link \n "+***url***)                               
>                               .setStream(null)
>                               .getIntent()
>                               .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
>                               activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
> ```