# Share photo on Google Plus using android sdk not by Share Intent

Tags: android, upload, google-plus, image-uploading

I have integrated Google+ using its android sdk and able to get PlusClient object as well.
I got basic information from [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started). In the same page at bottom there is another link for interactive post from where i got the below code which share the content. But its opening dialog and then share it.

Code :-

```
Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
      Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
          .setType("text/plain")
          .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
          .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
          .getIntent();

      startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
    }
});
```

My case is different as I have Image and Text already with me in my app, i just want to share them on the Google+ without any user interaction (except the login/sigin of user who wants to share it). And immediately after sharing the photo+text i will remove/clear the login of the user. So i only want to ask user for the authentication and the dialog for share should not appear. There will be a single button name **Share on G+** by clicking that button app will ask user for authentication and share the photo+text already selected by user.

**IMP NOTE :- Only user authentication pop up should be displayed and there after it must share the photo+text without any user interaction.**

I need some guidance on this as i have already integrated the android-sdk and i also have it working, Now only thing is sharing without user interaction. Please if anyone has any idea on this kindly help/guide me.

Comment: If anyone knows any workaround then it would be also great for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Sharing to Google+ must always be user-initiated, which ultimately makes for a better user experience when other users see a share from your app--they know that it has context for them.

The user interaction is actually pretty minimal. Once they hit the `Share` button, they will be taken to a share dialog that already has the content you have pre-populated. They can add a comment and some people they think would enjoy the post, and that's it.

Comment: There is no workaround for this? I know that user interaction is minimal but i want to make it like user comes to the picture only for login rest everything will be handled by App only...

Comment: Please help/guide me if you have any workaround which can help me in this..it would be really great for me....else at the end i know you are absolutely right and this thing i have already aware about...

Comment: There isn't a workaround. The Google+ API is a read-only API, meaning that the only way to share content is for users to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own google plus posts for your app.

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating