# How do I open native google plus app from inside my app for android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, google-plus, share, navigatetourl

I want users to be able to share a url link on google plus from inside my as3 app using navigateToUrl, but I want the native google plus app to open up, not go through mobile web browser. I am using the as3 function below for iOS which works perfectly fine:

```
function shareOnGooglePlus(event:Event):void {
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("gplus://plus.google.com/share?url=" + URL_LINK);
    navigateToURL(request, "_blank")
}
```

This function just isn't doing anything on android and I don't know why. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867989/open-google-plus-page-via-intent-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How post Image and Link URL in Google Plus from Android Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288099/how-post-image-and-link-url-in-google-plus-from-android-application)

Comment: So does the app xml manifest need to include an intent filter for google plus to get the URLRequest to work or something? Why would you need to do this though? You can open the native twitter and facebook apps on both android and ios just by using "fb://" and "twitter://" in the URLRequest, so why doesn't "gplus://" work for android?